# Aggregate SQL query to find % as compared to total

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a query that shows me count by store. I would like to find the % against total.

Given below is the SQL I have built:

```
select store, sum(sales), bill_date
from sales
where date = '2018-01-01'
group by store, bill_date
```

Output:

```
Store A,100,2018-01-01
Store B,123,2018-01-01
Store C,130,2018-01-01
Store D,113,2018-01-01
```

I would like to have one more column added that shows % of sales done by each store as compared against all stores. Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Please specify if it's MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ... you're using

Comment: Sorry its Postgres...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ANSI-standard window functions:

```
select store, sum(sales), bill_date,
       sum(sales) * 1.0 / sum(sum(sales)) over () as store_ratio
from sales
where date = '2018-01-01'
group by store, bill_date ;
```

The `* 1.0` is become some databases do integer division (so 1/2 = 0, not 0.5).  That might not apply to your database.

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know how could I modify this query further by one more level say by product name. Aggregation should happen by store and also product name. Thanks..

Comment: @Taukheer . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you can't figure out how to modify the query (by adding the product in the select and group by), then ask another question.